# Is there a name for bases like $\{ (1,1,1,1), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1) \}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

**Update:** Fixed another typo; thanks Jaap Scherphuis.

**Update:** Fixed some things; thanks 2'5 9'2.

Consider the vector space $F^{2^n}$ of $2^n$-tuples of elements of some field $F$.  This has a basis $\beta_n$ which, for the first few values of $n$, looks like:

$(n=0)$ : { (1) }

$(n=1)$ : { (1, 1), (0, 1) }

$(n=2)$ : { (1, 1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1) }

For $n = 3$:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\\\ 1 \\\\ 1 \\\\ 1 \\\\ 1 \\\\ 1 \\\\ 1 \\\\ 1 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 1 \\\\ 1 \\\\ 1 \\\\ 1 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 1 \\\\ 1 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 1 \\\\ 1 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\\\ 1 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 1 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 1 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

In general $\beta_n$ consists of:

- The vector $(1, 1, \ldots, 1)$
- A basis of the form $\beta_{n-1}$ for the subspace where the first $n/2$ elements are zero
- A basis of the form $\beta_{n-1}$ for the subspace where the last $n/2$ elements are zero, except without the first element.

**Questions:**

- Does this basis have a name?  Or does the corresponding matrix?
- Also, there are various ways we could generalize this to vector spaces of arbitrary finite dimension.  Do any of these have names?

**Background:**

I have a time series that I wanted to break down into "here's the average behavior, here's how the first half is different from the second half, and so on, recursively."

Comment: I'm a little confused by what $n$ is supposed to mean. You write "$n$-tuples" but when $n=3$ we are looking at $4$-tuples, where $4=2^2$.  I'm guessing where you have $n=1,n=2,n=3$ that should be $n=0,n=1,n=2$, and these are $2^n$-tuples. Does that sound right?

Comment: I also don't understand "a basis of the form $\beta_{n-1}$ for the subspace where the first $n/2$ elements are nonzero". Do you mean "...are _zero_"? If the first however many elements are nonzero, that does not make a subspace. Also if $n$ is something like $3$, then $n/2$ is not an integer. My previous comment suggests you want $2^{n-1}$ instead of $n/2$.

Comment: A nice way to order the matrix might be something like: $$\scriptsize\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1\\0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$This is an upper-triangular matrix where the number of $1$'s in the $i^{\text{th}}$-to-last row is the highest power of $2$ dividing $i$. (I guess I put the basis elements in as the rows here, which might not be standard.)

Comment: "Consider the vector space $F^{2^n}$ of n-tuples" Usually the set / space of n-tuples is denoted $F^n$.

Comment: Fixed some errors in the question; hopefully more comprehensible now.

Comment: It might help if you include the $8-$tuple case also. If I understand correctly, when interpreted as a sequence of binary numbers, you can get your basis from the recurrence
$$a_n =
\begin{cases}
(2^{2^m}+1)a_{n - 2^m}   & \text{if } n+1 = 2^{m+1}\\
2^{2^m}a_{n - 2^m} & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$ where $m = \lfloor \log_2(n)\rfloor$ and $a_0 = 1$.

Comment: What is the motivation for this basis?

Comment: @2'59'2 Fixed, thanks.  Having one of those weeks where I can only see what I *think* I wrote, not what I actually wrote...

Comment: @JairTaylor: updated

Comment: In your n=3 basis you have the zero vector, which is wrong because the zero vector can never be a part of any basis as it is vacuously a linear combination of other basis elements.

Comment: In a basis, order matters. You have three bullet points that describe how to build the next level basis. But if I use those bullet descriptions in order, I get vectors in a different order than what you have presented. Like your $\beta_2$ is $\{(1, 1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1)\}$, but following the bullet points in order I would construct  $\{(1, 1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0)\}$, swapping the order of the last two. Can you add something that explains the order you are using for vectors in these bases?

Comment: Or if you don't mind what order is used, that is good to know too.

Comment: @2'59'2 Not according to any definition of "basis" I've ever seen in print.  Usually it's described  as a linearly independent spanning subset.  It's not clear what an ordering would even mean for a vector space with uncountable dimension.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: Fixed, thanks.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Sorry but order does matter in a basis. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, the basis $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ is a different basis than $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$. For example the vector you'd traditionally call $\vec{e}_1$ is $\langle1,0\rangle$ wrt the first basis I wrote, and is $\langle0,1\rangle$ wrt the second basis. Because you have to align the coordinates in the coordinate vector with the elements from the basis.

Comment: I see that it is a convention to opt to not declare an ordering though. So I concede.